# What to do if Ubuntu cannot display your files in hdd

Tags: hard-drive

What to do about this error?

```
This location could not be displayed.
Sorry, could not display all the contents of "harddrive":Error when getting information for file'/media/user/harddrive/folder':input/output error
```

I need the files in my external hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

An input/output error usually is a sign of a failing hard disk.

You can check if that is indeed the case using `gnome-disks` from the package **gnome-disk-utility**.